# QtCreator crash upon editing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, graphics, qt-creator

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop Dell XPS 15 9550. Current kernel is 4.4.0-34. Display resolution is 3840x2160. I am using nvidia prime and currently the nvidia driver 370, but I select "Intel" in the prime-indicator by default. I don't know what other information is relevant, please feel free to ask.

My system is mostly working but there are a few issues:

- Sometimes (most times) Ubuntu takes a long while to shut down, don't know why.
- Sometimes when I edit a text file (say in gedit text editor), my system "doesn't like it", it seems to be lagging for no reason.
- Some programs often crash (Firefox for instance)
- Sometimes I get error messages "System program error detected".

None of these problems are so frustrating that I really tried to do something about it. But recently I starting working again on a Qt/C++ project using Qt Creator, and Qt Creator crashes all the time, making it unusable. Here is what happens: as soon as I start editing a file such as main.cpp in Qt Creator, it crashes. If I run it from the terminal with strace, all I can read is:

```
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

At first I thought something may be wrong with my Qt Creator, but now I think the fault is on Ubuntu (I have tried several versions of Qt Creator, several install methods, all produce the same effect). Although I have no clue what is going on, I suspect maybe the problem is related to the graphics driver? As well as my other issues described above?

If you could help me with this, it'd be great.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with QtCreator on the same machine model. At first, I also looked for the graphics drivers, but I noticed that Qt worked perfectly when run with `sudo`.

So I searched in environment variables, and I noticed that QtCreator works when `QT_LINUX_ACCESSIBILITY_ALWAYS_ON` is not set. I think this setting forces the screen reader to read the code, which Qt does not like.

After searching, I found a script `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90qt-a11y` that export this variable on session opening. Simply commenting on this line and restarting the session solved the problem.